# How to provide enum string as value of an attribute?

Tags: java, bean-validation, jackson2, struts2-jsr303-plugin

Enum:-

```
public StatusEnum {
   MISSING("00"), INVALID("01");
   ....
}
```

I'm trying to use these strings "MISSING", "INVALID" as an attribute field for JSR Validations:-

```
public class SomePojo{
 
  @NotNull(message = StatusEnum.MISSING.toString())  //this is invalid ofc, but this is what i want
  @Pattern(regexp="some pattern", message = StatusEnum.INVALID.toString())
  private string someField;

}
```

I need this so that when **i programmatically validate** an object against this class (javax validations), i want the constraintViolation object's getMessage to give me the enum string so that I can easily interpret the error.

I know i can put the strings directly but changing the enum will need change in the attributes as well which is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

The value for the message must be a constant expression. Instead of an Enum you can use a class with constants:

```java
public class Status{
    public static final String MISSING = "00";
    public static final String INVALID = "01";
}
```

And then use it:

```java
public class SomePojo{
  @NotNull(message = Status.MISSING)
  @Pattern(regexp="some pattern", message = Status.INVALID)
  private string someField;
}
```

Comment: if i do this, i can't automatically figure out the actual error in the constraintViolation object. I have to do if(violattion.message == "MISSING") {dothis();} else if (violation.message == INVALID)doThat(); and so on. It'll be easier with enum

Comment: I see, but I don't think it can't be done with an enum. What if you try to get the failing constraint in another way rather than by message? I am sure Hibernate validator provides something for that

Comment: They  provide this "payload" field in the validation annotations but it's too much code for doing this simple task.